# User input to multi-dimensional array (column)

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array:

```
 [ 0  0
   1  0
   2  0
   3  0
   4  0
   5  0 ]
```

How do I specify where the user input (using scanner) will go to in the array? I would like to add an integer to each position of the second column.

Comment: try something before asking question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an `array of array`, to get the number of rows, you use the length of your array.

For e.g, for this array: -

```
int[][] arr = new int[3][4];
```

`arr.length` gives you number of rows in the array, i.e. `3`. So, run a loop from `0 to arr.length`, to access each row.

Now, to access the `2nd column` of each row, you can do `arr[i][1]` in your loop: -

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    arr[i][1] = ...;  // your 2nd column for each row
}
```

Also, to get user input to fill your `2nd column` for each row, you have to read input for each row. So, you can guess where you need to read the user input - In `outer loop`, or in `inner loop`?

Comment: what does the 1 in arr[i][1] represent?

Comment: @Kronos.. `i` is the variable in your outer loop. `arr[i][1]` will be `arr[0][1]`, `arr[1][1]`, ... so on. for each row.

Comment: @Kronos.. Common. at least write some code. Come up with what you tried. Then you can get more help. I'm not going to just give away the code. You will not learn anything that way.

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant 1. When I have something to show you I will. At the moment I have no clue where to start for this problem, that is why I am asking for help.

Comment: `1` is the index of 2nd column. arr[0][1] means `1st row 2nd column`.

Comment: @Kronos.. Its no problem to ask for help. But on SO, generally we expect the asker to show some efforts. We understand that one cannot learn if he is given readymade code. So, please try it out. If you face any problem, we would be more than happy to help. Good Luck :)

Comment: Expecting is expecting. It is not code of conduct. Thank you for your help.